# magento 2.4 call stock alert via ajax

Tags: magento2.4, ajax, stock-alert

I'd like to implement the magento standard out of stock alert feature. This works out of the box for simple products but not for grouped products. I know there are ready make modules that extends this alert for grouped products but my grouped product page is heavily customized so these modules wouldn't work anyway so, I'd rather implement this feature myself.

In order to do this, I've simply created  a custom block in my vendor/module with its own phtml template. In this template, I have an html select tag with all the out of stock simple products associated to the main grouped product.

When the user selects an option from this dropdown, an ajax call should be made to the standard magento productalert controller and the alert should be saved in standard magento table.

In order to achieve this, I've added some jQuery on my phtml: I can retrieve the selected option, but when I try to call the productalert url via ajax, nothing happens:

```
- vendor/module/view/frontend/templates/outofstock.phtml

<div class="oos product alert stock">
    <select name="oos-select" id="oos-select">
        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("--Please choose an option--")) ?></option>
        <?php foreach($oos as $oosId => $oosLabel) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $oosId ?>"><?= $oosLabel ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#oos-select").on('change',function(){

            var productId = this.value;
            var basicUrl = "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>";
            var ajaxUrl = basicUrl.replace("product_id/xxx/", "product_id/" + productId + "/"); 
            
            alert(ajaxUrl);  // the url shows correctly

            jQuery.ajax({    // this call does nothing
                url: ajaxUrl,
                type: "POST",
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```